# Why does the query return a number instead of the row values?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Why does `cursor.fetchone()` return `{'1': 1}` instead of row values?

I expect something like `{'username': 'Bob', 'password': 'hunter2'}`.

```py
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor
# ...
mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=DictCursor)
# ...
cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
# ...
cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', [name, password])
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row) # {'1': 1}
```

Comment: It is returning row values.  The row is named `"1"`, and the value is `1`, because your select statement is `SELECT 1`.  What else were you expecting?

Comment: I expect something like `(Bob, hunter2)` because that's the row's values.  By `SELECT 1` I intend to get only 1 row and not multiple rows from the table.

Comment: Why did you write `cursorclass=DictCursor`? (Edit: nevermind, but maybe you should clarify that your question is not about why the result is a dictionary instead of a tuple)

Comment: That's not what `SELECT 1` means.  I think you're looking for `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting a column named 1 (because it's an implicit name for a constant "column" selected) that has a value 1.

If you did `SELECT 2 FROM ...` you'd get `{"2": 2}`.

If no rows match the FROM, you'd get `None` (and `cursor.rowcount` would be zero).

> I expect something like (Bob, hunter2) because that's the row's values.

Then you'll need to `SELECT username, password`, not `SELECT 1`. Then you'd get a dict `{"username": "Bob", "password": "hunter2"}`.

> ... and not multiple rows from the table

With your query, if there are multiple rows with the WHERE'd username and password, you'd get multiple rows of `{"1": 1}`. If you only want the first matching row, add `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting a column from the table you are selecting a literal value, which is 1. So MySQL must assign a column name to the value and uses a string that is the same value  as the column value. That would be ‘1’ in this case.

You can explicitly assign a column name by using AS:

```
SELECT 1 AS some_name …
```

It would appear that the SELECT statement is verifying a user id/password combination by seeing if a row is returned which will only occur if the user id and password match. The content of the row returned is not important.